# JSF -> Using one action listener for two action button

Tags: jsf

I have a managed bean in which i have defined two methods that performs two differents operations. I have defined in a .xhtml page two button which performs the two different operations.
I have created a ActionListener implementation class.  In this class i want to perform one of the two different operation depending on the value of the button. 
What should i code to retrieve the value of the button in the ActionListener implementation class and how should i define the two button to make sure that use the same action listener

Comment: "*In this class, I want to perform one of the two different operations depending on the value of the button*". Performing different operations depending upon the value (or some other attributes) of the button in a shared action(Listener) method is a design smell/flaw and should absolutely be avoided. This should instead be done based on which button is clicked using a separate action(Listener) for each command button or command link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably already know, the `ActionListener` interface defines an `abstract` method, called `processAction(ActionEvent event)`.

The parameter `ActionEvent` can be used to retrieve the source of the event, the old value/new value (when *attaching* the action listener to some specific components, etc).

So, you can get the component's client `id`, for example, by just doing:

```
package com.somepackage;
...
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void processAction(ActionEvent event) {
        String componentId = event.getComponent().getClientId();
        ...
    }
}
```

> ...and how should I define the two buttons to make sure that they use the same action listener?

For both of the buttons, you have to *nest* a `<f:actionListener>` and make sure its `type` attribute points to the fully-qualified class name of your action listener. For example:

```
<h:commandButton id="buttonA">
    <f:actionListener type="com.somepackage.MyActionListener" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:commandButton id="buttonB">
    <f:actionListener type="com.somepackage.MyActionListener" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "fully-qualified class name"?

Comment: If a class is called `MyClass` and it's defined within a package `com.something`, then the fully-qualified class name is `com.something.MyClass`.